# "Failed to suspend in time" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, graph

I am getting the following error when i use my app over a period of time between 10-15 minutes,the app hangs and fails to perform any operations further.I use all the functionality provided in the app.I am using Core Plot framework for graph functionality.I cannot figure out the cause of this error.
[image]

NOTE:When i check the memory usage with the help of Allocation tools...the usage does not go beyond 4.5 MB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you got CPU intensive tasks that are run on main thread?

That looks to me like the most likely culprit with this little information.

Comment: The CPU usage increases drastically sometimes during operations but not any fixed ones..

Comment: Maybe you need to 'thread' some part, there are several ways to do that, depending on the computation type.